# How to put some inputs inside one bitmask? #arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I have 14 inputs (that always updates/ change states) that I would like to read and put them all inside one bitmask.
Then, I'll use this bitmask to check different sequences that matters to me.
Is this the right way to do it?
I'm trying to print the mask on the monitor, and it doesn't show me the mask but separated bits.

```
uint16_t clowns_mask = 0b00000000000000;


uint16_t get_clowns_state() {
    for (uint8_t i = 34; i < 48; i++) {    // scan the input pins
        bitWrite(clowns_mask, i, digitalRead(i));
    }
    return clowns_mask;
}

void winning_check(uint16_t mask) {
    if ((mask & 0b11110000000000) == 0b11110000000000) {  // top row winning sequence
        digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(TOP_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, LOW);                    // =turn on
    } else if ((mask & 0b00001111100000) == 0b00001111100000) {  // mid row winning sequence
        digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(MID_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, LOW);                    // =turn on
    } else if ((mask & 0b00000000011111) == 0b00000000011111) {  // btm row winning sequence
        digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(BTM_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, LOW);  // =turn on
    } else {
        digitalWrite(TOP_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);  // =turn on
        digitalWrite(MID_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);  // =turn on
        digitalWrite(BTM_ROW_MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);  // =turn on
        digitalWrite(WINNING_SENSOR_PIN, LOW);
    }
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println(mask, BIN);
#endif
}


loop() {
   winning_check(get_clowns_state());
}
```

Comment: check this, may help bitWrite(clowns_mask, i-34, digitalRead(i));

Comment: _"it doesn't show me the mask but separated bits"_ What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in get_clowns_state(). clowns_mask is a 16-bit number, yet the bitWrite() calls attempt to set the non-existent bits 34 through 48 in clown_mask.

Change the bitWrite() call to:

```
bitWrite(clowns_mask, i - 34, digitalRead(i));
```

That way, bit 0 of clowns_mask will store the state of pin 34, and bit 14 of clowns_mask will store the state of bit 48.

Comment: Is there another way to print the binary number (clowns_mask) to the serial monitor without Serial.println(n, BIN)?

Comment: I don't understand. Perhaps create a new Stackoverflow question with the current code and what you'd like it to do.